# Reordering product tab under product image

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to reorder product description tab just under the product image in woocommerce single product page. I already hooked that by using these code

```
 add_action('init', 'avf_move_product_output');
function avf_move_product_output() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 5 );
}
```

But problem is the product image gallery showing under the product tab not uder the product image. I am little bit of confusing that, how to do this! Please someone help me to solve this. Thanks in advanced.

The link of single product page is here:
http://gadgets-update.com/af/shop/birthday/be-happy-bouquet-with-roses/

Thanks,
Waqar